# Apache rewrite rule to remove part of URL and everything after it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tried dozens of examples over the past couple of hours and can't get the desired results so I'm clearly missing something and/or doing something wrong.

So sorry to be asking such a basic question so similar to so many others...

*All I want to be able to do is remove **'/book-now'** from all URLs (when it exists) AND to remove anything/everything after it as well.*

For example:

> /category/type/book-now/13
>
> /category/type/book-now/13-course-title-example
>
> /category/type/book-now/13-course-title-example/23311-course-instance-in-this-location-example

should all rewrite (and 301 redirect) to:

> /category/type

Where 'category', 'type', '13', 'course-title-example', '23311', 'course-instance-in-this-location-example' are all variable.

So generic example would be:

> /[BEFORE]/book-now/[AFTER]

should simply become:

> /[BEFORE]

There's no need to specifically handle query strings as there won't be any, i.e. it's fine to lose them if they exist.

Comment: I should probably have said before, I'm using Apache 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the code I went with to achieve what I was after:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/book-now /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)book-now 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ book-now/$1 [L]
```

or this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/book-now/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That gives 500 Internal Server Error. 

If I set the redirect flag on the rule then it appends an internal server path to the end of the domain, forming an incorrect URI and the browser says the webpage isn't redirecting properly.

Comment: Please try the second solution above. starting with "or this"

Comment: Thank you so much for both suggestions.  I couldn't get the second suggestion to work either but combining both ideas, and having a little play, I came up with a solution that I whittled down to this simple bit of code: `RewriteRule (.*)/book-now /$1 [R=301,L]` that appears to be working as required.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: I'd vote your answer up as useful but looks like I need at least '15 reputation' to do so.